# Getting Eclipse to recognize automatic CUDA kernel variables and functions

Tags: eclipse, cuda

Is there a way to get Eclipse (Indigo) to know about the built-in variables and functions that are available to CUDA kernels?

Consider the following simple kernel

```
__global__ void myKernel()
{
    int x = threadIdx.x;
    __syncthreads();
}
```

The Eclipse IDE highlights "threadIdx" and "__syncthreads" with a "Symbol '*the built-in symbol*' could not be resolved" error message.  Is there a way to tell Eclipse these are actually implicitly defined?

Comment: Try using `#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>`. The symbols are defined in there. Comes part of the CUDA install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

flipchart is correct. `#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>` does the trick if the symbol `__CUDACC__` is defined beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

In cuda 11.3 you can add:

```
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>
```

Comment: With CUDA 12 this generates a warning about this header being an internal implementation detail, and it will go away soon. The warning recommends using `cuda_runtime.h`, which seems to do the trick similarly.